# java: как писать в InputStream/читать из outputstream?

Tags: java, потоки-данных, io, чат, бот

чтобы считать из inputstream надо сначала туда что-то положить, верно?

есть однопоточный чат-бот, работающий на inputstream-outputstream
хочу прикрутить его к боту вк ( и запускать в отдельном потоке для каждой беседы), только вот как подсунуть боту inputstream, в который будет писаться при получении от клиента вк? и как читать из outputstream-a в который пишет бот, чтобы передать в клиент вк

в с++/с# такой проблемы нет, там можно писать-читать stream, в java же они разделены и я не вижу ни одного способа писать в inputstream или читать из outputstream

Comment: по-моему предназначение этих классов не соответсвует вашим целям или их понимание неправильное.. output классы предназначены для записи в некий контейнер, а input - для чтения из оного, а не наоборот

Comment: окей, какой контейнер можно создать, чтобы ложить в него через outputstream а читать потом через inputstream.

Answer (score 1):

В java уже есть реализация подобных потоков, она вам скорее всего подойдёт, это `Piped` стримы [Output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html) и [Input](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html).

Например:

```
PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream();
PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputStream(in);
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));//Обёртка для удобной работы со строками
BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStremWriter(out));//Тоже самое для OutputStream
w.write("Hello world!\n");//\n означает перенос строки
w.flush();//стоит делать после окончания блока записей
System.out.println(r.readLine());//"Hello world!"
```